# how to create a batch file that takes 2 arguments from a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to have a batch file that takes two arguments from a txt file then pass these two arguments as parameters to a function.

i should use for loop because the text file contains these 2 arguments in every single line ,

here what i got till now

```
@echo off
for /F  "tokens=* EOL=# delims=" %%D in (C:\Users\ba\Desktop\New folder (3)\r.txt) do call:myd "%%~D" "%%~D"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use quotes in the filename, because it has spaces. But quotes have a special meaning to `for /f`, so you need to use the `usebackq` directive.

Second, you are telling it to get all tokens, (`tokens=*`) with no delimiters (`delims=`), essentially the entire line. But you want to pass two parameters. Assuming your file contains a list that looks something like `param1 param2`, you'll want to use a space as delimiter, and get tokens 1 and 2.

Finally, you'll want to reference the second param as `%%E` because it follows `%%D`.

Try:

```
@echo off
for /F  "usebackq tokens=1,2 EOL=# delims= " %%D in ("C:\Users\ba\Desktop\New folder (3)\r.txt") do call:myd "%%~D" "%%~E"
```

Comment: another point: to call another batchfile, use `call myd.bat` instead of `call :myd` (which tries to call a label). In `myd.bat` reference the parameters  as `%1` and `%2`.

Comment: @Stephan cite:`pass these two arguments as parameters to a function` doesn't necessarily mean an `external` batch function